# Spark scala error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

hey i tried to use spark with scala. When i try this code

```
    object d29 {
    def main(args: Array[String]){
    val name : String ="myspark"
    val master : String ="local[1]"
    val conf : SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(name).setMaster(master)
    val  spContext : JavaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf)
    val file = spContext.textFile("zed/text.csv")
    val mapped = file.map(s=>s.length)
    }
}
```

i got this error for the s : `missing parameter type`

thank you

Comment: Does it help when you specify the type of s?  `val mapped = file.map((s: String) => s.length)`

Comment: no it doesnt help ` type mismatch; found : String ⇒ Int required: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[String,?] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object d29 {
def main(args: Array[String]){
val name : String ="myspark"
val master : String ="local[1]"
val conf : SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(name).setMaster(master)
val  spContext = new SparkContext(conf)
val file = spContext.textFile("zed/text.csv")
val mapped = file.map(s=>s.length)
}
```

}

`JavaSparkContext` is Java wrapper of SparkContext. Since you are using Scala, no need wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Scala, then do not create a `JavaSparkContext`. Use `SparkContext` instead :

```
val spContext: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Then your code will work.

If you are using Spark 2, use the new `SparkSession` instead of `SparkContext`.

Comment: i'm using spark 1.6 no SparkSession